# How to Proxy Fontawesome Pro npm packages

Tags: npm, font-awesome, nexus

I work for a Company where our Frontend Build are on a Server with a very strict firewall policy

Therefore we use a Proxy (Nexus3) for `https://registry.npmjs.org` which works great.

Now i want to do the same for Fontawesome Pro 5

Fontawesome tells me to add those two lines in my `.npmrc` file see:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=${FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}
```

my old npmrc file had this line

```
registry=https://nexus.mycompany.com/repository/npm-proxy/
```

i tried the following:

```
registry=https://nexus.mycompany.com/repository/npm-proxy/
@fortawesome:registry=https://nexus.mycompany.com/repository/fontawesome/ <!-- which i created on the nexus side-->
//nexus.mycompany.com/repository/fontawesome/:_authToken=${FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}
```

but it doesn't work and i dont know if i need a diffrent setting on the nexus side or a diffrent setting on the npmrc side...

Answer (score 0):

We do have the same issue and we're asking the corresponding teams to add the Font Awesome Pro URL to the allowed list in the Firewall.